# How to configure SSL on Apache only with .crt file

Tags: apache, ssl, https

I'm not familiar with SSL configuration on Apache rsrs

But today, a client asked me to configure an Azure machine (Ubuntu 18.04 based) to be used with some websites.

All worked fine... I've installed Apache, PHP, Mysql, phpMyAdmin etc. But, before finishing the job, he asked me to install a wildcard SSL certificate for a domain and all sub-domains hosted on this server. He sent me an .CRT file and a Base64 in the email's body.

I tried using the Base64 as .KEY file, converting the .CRT file to .PEM (with openssl) and setup Apache VirtualHosts (port 443, obvious) as following:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /home/website/ssl/wildcard_cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/website/ssl/wildcard_cert.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /home/website/ssl/wildcard_cert.crt
```

`apache2ctl configtest` returns success, but when trying to restart the service, Apache can't go up. Checking the logs, there is an error with private key, as following:

```
[ssl:error] [pid 30401] AH02579: Init: Private key not found
[ssl:error] [pid 30401] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag
[ssl:error] [pid 30401] SSL Library Error: error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error
[ssl:error] [pid 30401] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag
[ssl:error] [pid 30401] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error (Type=RSAPrivateKey)
[ssl:error] [pid 30401] SSL Library Error: error:04093004:rsa routines:old_rsa_priv_decode:RSA lib
[ssl:error] [pid 30401] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag
[ssl:error] [pid 30401] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error (Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO)
[ssl:emerg] [pid 30401] AH02564: Failed to configure encrypted (?) private key [mydomain.com]:443:0, check /home/website/ssl/wildcard_cert.key
```

Commenting the SSL-related lines on conf file, Apache goes up fine, but only with HTTP.

Can someone help me?

Thanks! :)

Comment: since you have the .key and .crt file, 
all you need is to edit your default-ssl.conf file, 
then update the path of the "SSLCertificateFile" to where you store your .crt file, 
and also update the path of the "SSLCertificateKeyFile" to where you have your .key file, 
enable mod_ssl, the Apache SSL module, and mod_headers "sudo a2enmod ssl sudo a2enmod headers", 
also make sure your port 443 is enable, 
then restart your Apache server, 
try all these and let me know the out

Comment: The settings are ok. All you said is correct, but, reading my question, you will know my .key file is invalid, so I'm asking if there's another method to obtain the .key file (maybe from .crt) or enable ssl without the .key file (I think is impossible, but doesn't cost asking)... From your instructions, I missed enabling mod_headers only, but even enabiling it, stills not working because the .key file is wrong.

Comment: one of the reason why your .key file maybe wrong is if you do not generate the certificate signing request (CSR) on the Apache server you are using the key, if your client didnt ask you to generate the CSR from Azure machine (Ubuntu 18.04 based) the key will be invalid.

Comment: you can use this command to generate the csr file,"openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key -out server.csr " but replace server to the name of the domain you are trying to secure, then send him the .csr that is what he will use to generate the new cert and key file for you.

Comment: There is no way to extract a key from a certificate. A certificate is a public document; you can get the certificate for any website simply by visiting the website. The key is private, and if someone can get your key they can also impersonate you. It wouldn't make sense if you were able to extract the key (a secret) from the certificate (a public document).